# TFT LCD touch screen

Tags: touch

I am using MCU RX63N + ADS7843 + TFT LCD (GFT035AB320240Y).
I'm having a problem with touch handling.
Although I calibrate the ADC value after reading about it, but when using the fingers to touch the small buttons still can not get the exact touch position.
Is there any solution to this problem?
Look forward to the help of everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the bad calibration. Try calibrating with a touch pen and repeating it several times.